# Is this a bug in PHP's gmstrftime() function?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with PHP's gmstrftime() function.
Please look:

```
<?
$ts[]=1348573985; // '2012-09-25 13:53:05' (date returned from mysql's from_unixtime() function)
$ts[]=1233958620; // '2009-02-06 23:17:00' (date returned from mysql's from_unixtime() function)

foreach($ts as $t) {
    echo $t." => ".gmstrftime( "%d %B %Y - %H:%M", $t )."\n";
}
?>
```

Output will be:

```
1348573985 => 25 September 2012 - 11:53
1233958620 => 06 February 2009 - 22:17
```

As you can see, the first timestamp is 2 hours off (from mysql's output), which is normal because of timezone settings. But the second one is only 1 hour off but I did not change the timezone between the two gmstrftime() call's??

Is this a bug in PHP's gmstrftime() function, or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual for `gmstrftime`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php):

> Behaves the same as strftime() except that the time returned is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Greenwich Mean Time is the same all year around. This is different from the local time in the UK, which is set as GMT in winter, but "British Summer Time" (GMT+1, i.e. one hour ahead of GMT) in the summer. The same happens in Western Europe, which is GMT+1 in winter, but GMT+2 in summer.

Your MySQL database is presumably configured for local European time, so when converting a Unix timestamp that occurs during the summer, it adds an extra hour to line up with the Summer Time adjustment.

*In my opinion*, the best policy is to set all your systems to use 'UTC' (basically the same as GMT) and then convert to a local timezone "at the last minute". You could standardise on some other timezone, but UTC acts as a good baseline for debugging.

Comment: "The best policy is to set all your systems to use 'UTC'" --- personally I always run all my servers in the timezone I like more (the TZ I live at) and it works without issues as well.

Comment: @zerkms As long as you leave it at a set UTC offset, then yes, that would be fine. But if you set it to a location and let it account for summertime/DST adjustments, things can get confusing, *in my experience*.

Comment: my personal rule of thumbs are: 1) Use any system timezone 2) Always use the correct types for the dates and always work with dates using right tools. And this always works for me ;-) PS: http://rwec.co.uk/ --- uh-oh ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Fair enough :) Using UTC for everything is the "Lowest Common Denominator" approach - rather than ensuring all tools synchronise their handling of timezones, pretend the world all has one timezone.

Comment: once I worked in a company that followed the idea "let's think there is one timezone" - the code (I'd even say spaghetti so called the code) was full of magic numbers and other time-related magic. That was only caused by laziness to read about how to handle dates in oracle properly ;-)

Comment: Problem is that we're seeing this problem on IP.Board forum after importing data from VBulletin.

Comment: anyone know of a way how we can fix this easily?

Comment: @Erik Depends exactly what problem you are seeing. If the MySQL data has timezone in tact, you may be able to update it to the timezone IP.Board is expecting. However, if the timezone information wasn't copied when you exported and imported, it may be trickier to work out the "correct" value for each date. Either way, the question you asked is now answered - PHP is behaving correctly.

Comment: @zerkms Partly depends what timestamps your working with - for user submissions to a forum, respecting the server's timezone settings is pretty irrelevant. And in the travel industry where I work, flight times are represented as "local time", but I've yet to see an API that indicates what timezone that actually is, so making our code perfectly timezone-aware is impossible. :| PS: Thanks for the heads-up re rwec.co.uk - some kind of Wordpress exploit I suspect :(

Comment: @IMSoP: "Partly depends what timestamps your working with" --- in the software I'm currently developing (postgresql based) there is a lot of working with dates and not even a single operation with php's `time()` and unix timestamps at all. But indeed - probably I haven't met yet tasks when this solution is not appropriate :-)